# "People with different profiles" or "people with a different background"

Tags: word-choice

Speaking about technical and non-technical people (management), which word is the best in this case? *Profile* or *Background?*

The whole sentence is *"To provide training for people with [different profiles] | [a different background]"*

Comment: I would suggest using "expertise" rather than "profile" or "background".

Comment: LOL @FumbleFingers, there isn't anything similar between both questions.

Comment: The way I see it, the choice between *profile* and *background* in your context is entirely a matter of opinion, so the only aspect that would be On Topic is the plurality (for which you've presented both options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither; say what you mean: "...people with different levels of technical knowledge" / "...people with different technical aptitudes".

The terms "profile" and "background" are very general and if you're referring to levels of technical expertise, you need to use the word "technical" in order to make that known.

Depending on the context, you could go even more specific - "...people with different levels of programming experience" for example.